# Why does a switch-case statement on a string constant require a default in Visual Studio 2019 (prior to 16.0.3) but not in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I am trying out Visual Studio 2019 on a code base written in Visual Studio 2017, and am immediately finding a build issue. I have a `switch case` statement in which the case is selected on a constant string. This doesn't have a default case, which is fine in Visual Studio 2017, but throws a build error in Visual Studio 2019.

I can resolve the issue by adding a default case, but I would like to avoid a code change and just change a compiler setting if possible, to avoid the need for a pull request. In any case it would be good to understand the reason for the issue.

```
public class Program
{
    public const string Database = "MongoDB";

    public static string GetDb()
    {
        switch (Database)
        {
            case "MongoDB":
                return Database;
        }
    }
}
```

A github repository containing the example solution can be found at
https://github.com/martineyles/NoDefaultCase
This includes an archive of the example solution in the state before it was added to github.

In Visual Studio 2017, the output of the build is:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: NoDefaultCase, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  NoDefaultCase -> C:\Users\MartinEyles\source\repos\NoDefaultCase\NoDefaultCase\bin\Debug\NoDefaultCase.exe
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

In Visual Studio 2019, the output of the build is:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: NoDefaultCase, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Users\MartinEyles\source\repos\NoDefaultCase\NoDefaultCase\Program.cs(9,30,9,35): error CS0161: 'Program.GetDb()': not all code paths return a value
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am targeting .net framework 4.7.2 and the default language version. I have also tried reducing the language version to C# 6.0 and setting the language version manually to C# 7.3 with the same results.

The specific version of Visual Studio I am using are:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 
Version 15.9.11
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.9.11+28307.586
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.7.03056
```

and

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 
Version 16.0.0
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.0.0+28729.10
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.7.03056
```

The issue is resolved in:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019
Version 16.0.3
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.0.3+28803.352
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.7.03056
```

Comment: Is it giving you a build error, or a build warning?  A default case shouldn't be required.

Comment: It compiles in 2019 for me with C# language version set to 7.3 (if I replace MongoDatabase with something else)

Comment: @Amy, my target framework is set to .NET framework 4.7.2. My language version is default, but in VS2017 that says latest major version and in VS2019 it says latest supported minor version

Comment: @Amy I have tried changing the C# version to 7.3 manually and rebuilding, but it still fails, so I suspect the issue is something other than the C# version number.

Comment: I have updated the example to return a string, as this gives the same result without requiring externally defined types.

Comment: Well, you are right. The issue does occur in the non-preview version of VS2019. You should raise it with Microsoft. In the meantime, consider using the C# 8.0 beta compiler in VS 2019 - it doesn't exhibit the issue.

Comment: I can confirm that the issue doesn't occur with the C# 8.0 beta compiler, but this would still require a pull request as this changes the project file.

Comment: This has also been logged at:

    https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/520522/switch-case-without-default-no-longer-compiles-in.html#

but I am not certain if this is a bug or a setting that needs altering, so I still think it has relevance here at the moment.

Comment: This is a beautiful case of "is this a bug they rightly fixed, or a feature they should keep". To me it's a no-brainer: earlier compilers should not have accepted this and VS 2019's behavior is correct. Even if this code has reasonable semantics, it is extremely brittle and undesirable to allow compilation to succeed or fail based only on the *value* of a string constant. There's reasonable disagreement possible about this, though, especially depending on how wide-spread this pattern is in code in the wild (I should hope, not very -- but per mjwills, it sounds like newer versions walked back.)

Comment: On second thought, though, this is exactly what you could exploit as a feature: a sort of misbegotten preprocessor-ish trick to reliably spot code that needs to be changed when a new feature is introduced. Ugly -- yet useful.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in 16.0.3 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.0.3

Comment: I can confirm that the example code builds in 16.0.3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like *either* the specification will be updated with new rules on reachability, *or* this is a bug in Roslyn, probably due to changes introduced with switch expressions.

The important question for the compiler is whether the end of the method is reachable - which it will be if and only if the end of the switch statement is reachable.

The [ECMA C# 5 standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm) section 13.8.3 describes the reachability of the end of a switch statement:

> The end point of a switch statement is reachable if at least one of the following is true:
>
> - The switch statement contains a reachable break statement that exits the switch statement.
> - The switch statement is reachable, the switch expression is a non-constant value, and no default label is present.
> - The switch statement is reachable, the switch expression is a constant value that doesn’t match any case label, and no default label is present.

None of these seem to be the case in your example:

- There are no break statements
- The switch expression is a constant value
- The constant value *does* match a case label

So with C# 5 rules, the end point of this switch statement is *not* reachable, and it should compile with no problems. The [draft specification in GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/statements.md) has the same text, so it doesn't look like it's changed there yet...

Comment: The fact it compiles in C# 8 (beta) suggests it is a bug. I suppose we'll find out one way or the other soon enough!

Comment: This has been confirmed as a bug by the Roslyn team. The issue is referred to on their GitHub page:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/35011

Comment: The [Visual Studio 16.0.3 Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes#16.0.3) indicate that the issue is resolved in this version, and I can confirm that the example code builds in 16.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

> In C# 6, the match expression must be an expression that returns a
>   value of the following types:
>
> a char.
>  
>   a string. 
> a bool.
>  an integral value,
>  such as an int or a long.
>   an enum value.
>  **Starting with C# 7.0, the match expression can be any
>   non-null expression.**

the documentation said that with c# 7.0 the match expression can be any non-null expression.
in c# 7 , string become a nullable type so you must add the default case ( for the null case )

Comment: The code base uses C# 7 features, but it still compiles fine in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: With the new features of Visual studio 2019 : 
A switch expression must always return a value. However, the code will still compile even if that’s not true (i.e. the cases do not cover all possible values) 
The compiler will only emit a warning for the above code. If at runtime the tested value is not matched by any case, an InvalidOperationException will be thrown.
https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/1489/csharp-8-visual-studio-2019

Comment: I am receiving a build error, not a warning.
CS0161  C# '': not all code paths return a value

Comment: I have tried extracting the relevant code in a new project and setting the C# language version in project advanced build properties to 6.0, but this still fails to compile with the same build error in Visual Studio 2019, and also continues to build successfully in visual studio 2017.

Comment: `A switch expression must always return a value.` This code does **not** contain a switch expression.

Comment: @MartinEyles: VS2017 supports C# 7.0 as the default version.

Comment: It's not clear to me what those reference docs intend to mean by "any non-null expression", but I suspect it's *actually* intended to be "any expression with a type". It's not trying to prevent null string values, which have *always* been possible.